# What's the plus mean before style in CSS (Not selector)

Tags: css

What does the plus sign in the following code meaning?

```
#navigator{
    position: fixed;

    z-index: 99;
    +margin-left: -980px;
}
```

Comment: Nothing. It's just a typo.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5860304/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM, that older question deals with tricks in *selectors* and does not describe a trick that consists of *only* a plus sign. So this is more likely either a typo or a misunderstanding (of trickery).

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised that that plus sign did something hackish in older browsers, similarly to _ or * before selectors.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I'm not stating that it is definitely a trick, just pointing out what it might be.